# Is there any benefit to update new version of jquery library on each release to my site?

Tags: jquery, performance

Is there any benefit to update new version of jquery library on each release to my site?

Can my other added jquery code and plugins stop work on new library added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depending on how you use it and the nature of each release. Read the release notes carefully and do a comprehensive test before you deploy.

Here are some of the reasons I'll upgrade:

- Performance gain
- Specific bug fixes which conern my usage
- New features which I find useful

Some may say "if it ain't broke, don't fix it". However, the more you delay the upgrade of the version you use, the harder it is the next time round a new release comes.

Compatibility with existing plugins is a major concern. The plugin owners might give updates about the comaptibility. Whatever it is, test, test and test.